# Velocity.js: scroll element's x-axis

Tags: javascript, html, velocity

I want to scroll `#carousel` `500px` on `x-axis`. But I can't understand why `velocity` `function` does not do anything... Where is a mistake?

**HTML:**

```
   <div class="carousel" id="carousel">
     <div class="carousel__scroller" id="carousel__scroller">
       <ul>
         ...
         <li class="carousel__item">...</li> 
         ...
       </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
```

**SCSS:**

```
.carousel {
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    height: 150px;
    z-index: 2;
    outline: 1px solid black;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;

  &__scroller {
    position: absolute;
    background: lightgreen;
    width: 375000px;
    height: 100%;

    ul {
      height: 100%;

      li {
        height: 100%;
        line-height: 40px;
        background: lightgreen;
        position: absolute;
        outline: 1px solid white;
        padding-left: 10px;
        width: 100vw;
        float: left;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**JS:**

```
...
    $('#carousel').velocity("scroll", {
       axis: "x",
       offset: "500px",
       duration: 250,
       easing: "ease-in-out"
    });
...
```

**UPDATE**

jQuery alternative works well:

```
$('#carousel').animate({
    scrollLeft: '500'
}, 250);
```

But I still want to use `Velocity.js`. Still no luck with it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was.. I forgot to provide a `container`.

This is a working example:

```
    $carouselScroller
        .velocity('scroll', {
            container: $carousel,
            offset: slide * screen.width,
            duration: 200,
            axis: 'x',
            easing: 'linear',
            complete() {
                //some onComplete fn
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

velocity **2.0** expects a unit (px or %):

```
$('#carousel').velocity({
    scrollLeft: '500px'
}, 250);
```

https://github.com/julianshapiro/velocity/wiki/Property---ScrollLeft